# How long do new tyres last off the bike?

Tags: tire, storage

I'm thinking of buying 2 identical sets of tyres for my bike, one to fit immediately, and one to keep in the house as a replacement set when the first ones fail.

I'm assuming that this could be anywhere from 12–24 months, maybe more.

Will the second set of tyres still be in good condition after having been stored for that long?

And as a follow-up question, what are the best conditions to store them?

Comment: Fair comment, that question has some useful answers already. Feel free to close, thanks! :)

Comment: Let me add one data point to the discussion: I just replaced the original 700x23C front tire from the bike that I bought new in 1998.  The original tire had blown a split in the fabric about 1" / 2.5 cm long.  The original tire had lasted 18 years, although the bike hadn't been ridden for about 12 of those years, and the tire only had 3000 km / 2000 miles on it.  Also, in the US car tires are thought to be safe for about six years before they are affected by rubber degradation.

Comment: If stored in the house (not the garage, and not in a dank basement), and kept away from sunlight and heat, a bike tire should easily last 10 years (with the possible exception of "gumwall" tires).